# How do I move Plotly.js legend off second y axis

Tags: javascript, plotly

Plotly.js defaults to have the legend covering the second y axis. Here is their own code pen example of it happening:
https://codepen.io/plotly/pen/36d6c70e8fa17e471fa68788abbed90f

```
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3], 
  y: [40, 50, 60], 
  name: 'yaxis data', 
  type: 'scatter'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [2, 3, 4], 
  y: [4, 5, 6], 
  name: 'yaxis2 data', 
  yaxis: 'y2', 
  type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

var layout = {
  title: 'Double Y Axis Example', 
  yaxis: {title: 'yaxis title'}, 
  yaxis2: {
    title: 'yaxis2 title', 
    titlefont: {color: 'rgb(148, 103, 189)'}, 
    tickfont: {color: 'rgb(148, 103, 189)'}, 
    overlaying: 'y', 
    side: 'right'
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

I cannot get the legend to move more to the right. I have tried adjusting the margin/padding on the plot, the x position of the legend, the margin/padding on the legend, the overall size of the div, and the orientation of the legend.

On the topic of legend orientation, I could potentially put the legend below the plot to solve this problem. However, I am also having trouble implementing that. Here is my legend layout code:

```
legend: {orientation: 'h',
        y: -0.17,
        x: 0,
        font: {
            family:'Roboto',
            size: 10,
            color: 'rgb(54, 54, 54)'}
        },
```

and here is what my graph looks like:
[image]

Clearly there is a lot of code missing here and this isn't a working example of the problem, but the orientation is not changing to horizontal.

Comment: That's quite a lot of traces. I think that the best option would be still moving it under the plot, but if you can't do that, check out my edited answer.

Comment: The issue I was having with not changing to horizontal was fixed by using the most recent plotly library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about placing it under the plot? Also you can adjust it's position with changing the `x` and `y` values inside the `legend` property.

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3],
  y: [40, 50, 60],
  name: 'yaxis data',
  type: 'scatter'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [2, 3, 4],
  y: [4, 5, 6],
  name: 'yaxis2 data',
  yaxis: 'y2',
  type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

var layout = {
  title: 'Double Y Axis Example',
  yaxis: {
    title: 'yaxis title'
  },
  yaxis2: {
    title: 'yaxis2 title',
    titlefont: {
      color: 'rgb(148, 103, 189)'
    },
    tickfont: {
      color: 'rgb(148, 103, 189)'
    },
    overlaying: 'y',
    side: 'right'
  },
  legend: {
    y: 1,
    x: 1.1,
    bgcolor: 'transparent',
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="myDiv" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;">
    <!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
  </div>
  <script>
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT CODE GOES HERE -->
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I thought about that. Oddly, I cannot get my actual code to produce a legend with a horizontal orientation. I am updating my question to include a screenshot.

Comment: 1.1, of course! Do you know if plotly has a giant list of the acceptable range of each formatting input? I tried all kinds of integers, but I don't know why 1.1 didn't occur to me. I also think horizontal orientation would be great, but I really can't get it to work.

Comment: @Murenrb If you have more issues with legend, please check https://plot.ly/javascript/legend/ There's a lot of info about legend there.

Comment: @ Kind user, thanks for the link! I don't want to sound ungrateful at all, but that site is not actually too helpful. I had read through it exhaustively before this post and the problem is it doesn't call out all the possible properties or value ranges those properties can be set to. Like this x=1.1 value. It would be nice for plotly to put out a huge list of all properties and value ranges for their library. But I understand that that takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with most of their documentation as well - they tell you what the property is for, but not what the acceptable values for the property are and what each one does.  You can set the legend to be horizontal by doing the following:

```
layout:{
  orientation: "h"
}
```